# Application error and logs not loading, what steps to take?

Tags: java, spring, heroku

I've been getting the following error page, when visiting my app:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

However, `heroku logs --tail` does not return anything. If I go to the dashboard through web (https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/app-name/logs), the logs window keeps loading but nothing is shown.

I have nothing to go on, and Heroku won't accept a ticket of a free app. Does anyone know any more steps I can take to trace the error?

**Additional info**:

- The build logs all look fine:

  ```
       BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 49s
       5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
       Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
       Compressing...
       Done: 85.2M
       Launching...
       Released v3
       https://app-name.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
  ```
- I am creating a spring Java API, it works fine when I try to run it locally. If I try to run it through `$heroku local` I do get an error:

  [FAIL] No Procfile and no package.json file found in Current Directory - See run --help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue. I just added `system.properties` to root folder of spring app and this file contained 1 line:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

[Heroku procfile documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).

[Spring documentation for Heroku deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/cloud-deployment-heroku.html)

Comment: Did the trick! I also still had to generate the Procfile (how-to also present in Spring documentation). The only thing missing was specifying that a .jar file had to be built (see more info here for gradle users: https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/)